# Scraping data from Highcharts using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, highcharts

I am trying to scrape data from highchart. I took a look at similar questions, but didn't understand how script_execute works or how could I detect js using my browser. Here is my current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Core settings
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\X\Y\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

stats_url = 'https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/statistics/'

driver.get(stats_url)
driver.find_element_by_link_text('by Source').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('custom-date-range').click()
year = driver.find_element_by_id('date-range-start')
year.click()
for i in range(5): # goes back 5 years
    year.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
driver.find_element_by_id('date-range-submit').click()
```

I want to scrape the "download" data from the graph, (not only for this page for many pages though). And when I use custom search option, csv file that automatically generated by the website is not updated. So only way is to scrape the data from the graph. How I could do it ?

Comment: The person that gave a negative vote could please provide the answer ?

Comment: I didn't give negative review, but I think it's a reaction to issues in your code: 1. sleep instead of proper synchronization/waits; 2. xpaths you are using are 101 on how not to use xpath. 3. number 2 in combination with lack of any comments makes it a puzzle, not readable code.

Comment: Oh I am not really accustomed with selenium but let me edit it. Bu I am not sure if sleep time or find_element_by_xpath has something to do with the question that I asked

Comment: Also could you please tell me why 101 on how not to use xpath :D ? I am willing to learn

Comment: problem is that if you don't have a proper general setup (such as synchronization / waits), and someone suggests a solution to problem you asked about, the solution may not work for reasons unrelated to solution itself. So it becomes a lengthy debugging session. Thus best is to provide clean code, that works reliably, and is only missing something you don't know or understand, so the whole question is concentrated on proper topic, and not on troubleshooting other issues in a script.

Comment: as for xpath, the 101 is: 1 - avoid using //* (it doesn't help with readability, and also is least performant of all options); 2 - avoid using place-based location (e.g. [1], [2], etc); 3 - limit xpath to meaningful elements, that represent something important, don't try to follow the whole subtree; 4 - don't use xpath, if element can be identified in a better way. So for example: `find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="side-nav"]/ul/li[2]/a')` becomes `find_element_by_partial_link_text("Downloads")`.

Comment: Selenium has a method called `find_element_by_id()`. Use that instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I will re-edit it then, but any recommendations about highcharts?

Comment: I'm not sure what that is. Highcharts is JavaScript-specific. You could grab the CSV data and make a similar chart using `matplotlib`. I'm no expert on that though. :-)

Comment: It is not just for one addon but for many of them. Also when I use custom range, the changes are not reflected to csv file, I don't know why

Comment: You need to do this for these add-ons from mozilla only or you are looking for a generic solution from other site? Because mozilla data is much easier to get without even using Selenium

Comment: Could you please tell me the way? Because when you choose a custom range in Mozilla, corresponding csv file is not filled with those values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed one thing.

It seems true that:

> "when I use custom search option, csv file that automatically
>   generated by the website is not updated".

But actually it is not true. It is updated, but the **maximum "custom data range"** seems to be **1 year**.

For example, if you set from `2013-09-23` to `2017-10-23` the .csv(.json) generated **has max the data of 1 year** (in this example from `22/10/2016` to `21/10/2017`).

You can better notice this if you play with the "extremes".

For example with:

```
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/statistics/downloads-day-20131023-20141023.json
```

- first element: `{"date": "2014-10-23", "count": 212730, "end": "2014-10-23"}`
- last element: `{"date": "2013-10-24", "count": 163094, "end": "2013-10-24"}`

if you change with:

```
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/statistics/downloads-day-20131023-20141024.json
```

- first element: `{"date": "2014-10-24", "count": 215105, "end": "2014-10-24"}`
- last element: `{"date": "2013-10-25", "count": 168018, "end": "2013-10-25"}`

Or with:

```
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/statistics/downloads-day-20131022-20141023.json
```

will be again :

- first element: `{"date": "2014-10-23", "count": 212730, "end": "2014-10-23"}`
- last element: `{"date": "2013-10-24", "count": 163094, "end": "2013-10-24"}`

So, in order to get the data of the last 5 years you could do:

```
import subprocess
interestedYears=5;
year=1
today="2017-10-23"
tokenDataToday= today.split("-")
dateEnd=tokenDataToday[0]+tokenDataToday[1]+tokenDataToday[2]
url= "https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/statistics/downloads-day-"

while year <= interestedYears:
     yearStart= str(int(float(tokenDataToday[0]))-year)
     dateStart=yearStart+tokenDataToday[1]+tokenDataToday[2]
     #print("dateStart: " + dateStart)
     #print("dateEnd: " + dateEnd)
     tmpUrl=url+dateStart+"-"+dateEnd+".csv"
     cmd = 'curl -O ' + tmpUrl
     print(cmd)
     args = cmd.split()
     process = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
     stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
     dateEnd=dateStart
     year = year+1
     print("-----------------------------")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I somehow figured it out before I set a bounty for this question but also wanted to learn about how to scrape data from highcharts

Answer (score 6):

Mozilla provides a simple REST API to get the stats, so you don't need to use Selenium.

With the `requests` module:

```
url = "https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/statistics/downloads-day-20170823-20171023.json"
data = requests.get(url).json()
```

To select the range, simply update the dates in the URL.

But if you are still willing to scrap the chart with selenium:

```
dates = driver.execute_script("return Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].xData");
users = driver.execute_script("return Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].yData");
downloads = driver.execute_script("return Highcharts.charts[0].series[1].yData");
```

Comment: Actually, I figured out that I could use REST API yesterday, but I think there is not enough documentation about scrapping highcharts. Could you please explain, how do you know the chart actually corresponds to Highcharts.charts[0] ? I couldn't find it by visualizing source page

Comment: `Highcharts.charts[0]` is the first chart in the page. To get the chart related to a DOM element: `Highcharts.charts[document.querySelector("#head-chart").dataset["highchartsChart"]]`